# Get the touch event to a specific area like photo gallery in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, touch, photo-gallery

In my app for iPhone/iPad (in Objective-C), there are some UiButton's and other events and an UiImageView. Image covers the whole screen and i want that when one touches the upper or bottom area of screen(means suppose one button in the upper area), then the image resizes to a specific  size.

But i am not able to recognize if one touches the upper area or not, like in the Photo Gallery of the iPhone(where if i touches the upper/lower area the navigation button appears, the same thing I want in my app).

I already have the touch events in my app:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}
```

If somebody has any idea or solution please let me know.

Comment: The navigation will show up where you press in the Photo Gallery, not just the upper/lower area.

Comment: Yes, i means in Photo Gallery if i touch in the lower area of  iphone then it shows the navigation area, otherwise just shows the image on the full screen----------the same behavior i want in my app.

Comment: When you tap in the middle of the image it will also show the navigation. When you tap again the navigation will go away. So there is no need to detect if the user tapped in the uppe or lower area of the view. Just detect if the user tapped anywhere in the view.

Comment: yes i know...but my question is how can i recognize that now it touches on a particular element or area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious solution would be to subclass the UIImageView, then override it's *touchesBegun:withEvent:* method and in that method check where the actual touch happened:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch * touch = (UITouch *)[touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];

    if (location.y > some_arbitrary_value || location.y < some_other_arbitrary_value) 
    {
         //touched upper or lower part
    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but i don't have any specific points to restrict the area as there are some dynamic controls which are being generated at run time.

Comment: So? Just get the frames of those controls and use them in this function.

Comment: Hi...thanks it works perfectly now.  I have one more question ---  In my app there is UIScrollViewer(uiimageview inside this), when the userinteractionenabled=true, then no touch event fires in the app. How can i enable the touch events with userinteractionenabled=true.